# maximal separated quotient scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, not necessarily separated. Is there a notion "its maximally separated quotient"? This means, a separated scheme $Y$ with a morphism $X \to Y$, such that it is initial in all morphisms from $X$ to a separated scheme.

In other words, does the inclusion functor

{ separated schemes} $\to$ {schemes}

admits an adjoint?